Snowflake CSV File Format Issues: Handling Escaped Quotes and Backslashes in Unenclosed Fields
Question:
I'm loading data from Azure Blob Storage into Snowflake using Snowpipe. I have defined a file format with the following settings:

CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT my_csv_format TYPE = 'CSV'
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"' ESCAPE = '\' SKIP_HEADER = 1
ENCODING = 'UTF8';

When loading data, I'm encountering issues with the following two cases:

"James \"Doug\" Carwile left a review at the client site - perfect"
"C:\Program Files\Switch\TN_FTP Pro\"

In the first case, the data is loading correctly as it is escaping the backslash () near the word Doug. However, in the second case, the backslash at the end of the file path is causing the last quote to be escaped, thus messing up the load.
Is there a way to adjust the file format or another approach to handle both cases correctly? Specifically, I want to ensure that:
In the first example, the backslash escapes the quote correctly.
In the second example, the backslashes in the file path are treated as literal characters, not as escape sequences.
Any help or guidance on how to properly configure the file format or preprocess the data would be greatly appreciated!

what your examples show is that "the internal double quotes are escaped. BUT the escape token is not escaped. So this data is not escaped correctly/consistantly. So is not valid to be in a format like CSV. It needs to be exported correctly, and is unrecoverable as it is.
